# HBase table size not changing after inserting data

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hbase

i am trying to monitor my hbase table size while inserting data. at first i had 2 rows and size was 12.7k; after adding 10 rows it increased to 24.5 then i inserted 2000 rows but the size was still 24.5 so i added another 2000 rows and its still 24.5!
is this normal?

Comment: What metrics are you looking at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so apparently hbase keeps data in RAM or cache and i had to restart hbase to see the table size on hard drive using this command:
hdfs dfs -du -h  /hbase/data/default/myTable